# Ignore adapter creation when adaptee already of correct type

Tags: python, design-patterns, adapter

I have the following setup:

```py
class Target(Base):

  def __init__(name: str):
    self.name = name


class Adapter(Target):

  def __init__(self, adaptee: Base, name: str):
    super().__init__(name=name)
    self.adaptee = adaptee


def as_target(adaptee: Base, name: str):
  if isinstance(adaptee, Target):
    return adaptee
  else:
    return Adapter(adaptee, name)
```

I am wondering if I could get rid of `as_target` function and instead handle the logic on adapter creation.

Semantically, it would have the following meaning:

```py
class Adapter(Target):

  def __init__(self, adaptee: Base, name: str):
    if isinstance(adaptee, Target):
      self = adaptee
    else:
      super().__init__(name=name)
      self.adaptee = adaptee
```

I've tried playing around with overriding `__new__` but I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
class Base:
    pass


class Target(Base):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(type(self).__name__, repr(self.name))


class Adapter(Target):
    def __new__(cls, adaptee: Base, name: str):
        if isinstance(adaptee, Target):
            return adaptee
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, adaptee: Base, name: str):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.adaptee = adaptee


print(Adapter(Base(), "a"))  # Adapter('a')
print(Adapter(Target("b"), "c"))  # Target('b')
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was trying to make it work without implementing `__init__` which clearly makes no sense now that I see the correct solution. :)